# Is the expression "To date, it's the first..." redundant?

Tags: expressions, redundancy

I have read expressions similar to the following multiple times in scientific papers:

"Our study is the first to date to prove that..."
"To date, our study is the first to..."

I just realized that these expressions might be redundant because if a study is truly "the first" to do something, it will forever be the first to do so. Thus, the addition of "to date" is pointless because the fact that the study was the first will never change at a later point in time.

Is this correct?

Comment: Future studies might prove the same thing, but in a different way. Or a future study might invalidate the proof, by establishing a different result in a more credible way, and/or finding a flaw in a previous proof.

Comment: In many contexts you might use "first" to mean either the chronologically oldest example of something, or the first to be discovered/analysed/published (e.g. "first evidence of Vikings in the Americas"). Using "to date" clarifies this a bit, although there are other ways of expressing this distinction.

Comment: I think it's redundant, but it's a common expression.